# VisualForce page doesn’t show up as an option after I create new button

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I have created a Custom Object(Employee__c) and I have created a VisualForce Page for that custom object and now I like to add a custom button to open any other custom visual force page.

> > Setup>> Create>>Objects>>Employee>>Custom buttons & links.
> >
> > Action Type: custom Visualforce
> >
> > Visualforce Page: **I do not see my custom visualforce page here**

here is my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="employee_vfp_Controller" showheader="true" sidebar="true">
   <apex:form >

   //....more code

   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **standard controller** as well.

The custom object's Standard Controller must be set to make that page visible in Button, Links or Action.

Page looks like:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Employee__c" extensions="employee_vfp_Controller" showheader="true" sidebar="true">
   <apex:form >

   //....more code

   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: which standard controller?

Comment: @AbuHamzah The custom objects Standard Controller must be set to make that page visible in Button, Links or Action

Comment: after I have added standard controller as per your answer, now I'm getting : Error: Unknown constructor 'Employee_vfp_Controller.Employee_vfp_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Comment: @AbuHamzah You will need to define a constructor in class which takes `ApexPages.StandardController` as argument.